# mute and unmute button toggle html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, togglebutton, mute

I've understood how to mute an `<audio>` sound object by putting this code :

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ambiance').muted = true; return false">
    mute sound
</a>
```

Now I'm searching how to mute/unmute my sound using the same button with the option to toggle it ?

Can anyone give me directions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var audioElm = document.getElementById('ambiance'); audioElm.muted = !audioElm.muted;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.unmute {
  background-image: url(http://franriavilla.in/images/unmute.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mute {
  background-image: url(http://franriavilla.in/images/mute.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio id="track" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="audio/ThemePackNet.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<div class='unmute' onclick="document.getElementById('track').muted = !document.getElementById('track').muted;$(this).toggleClass('mute')"></div>
```