# Adding mute button for background music

Tags: jquery, html, css

YES, I know background music that auto-plays is the absolute worst, but despite our pleas and attempts to discourage the client from having this on his website, he won't give in. Ultimately, it's what he wants (i.e. no business).

So anyway, I have added the background music using the code below. It plays automatically on the opener page, however I would like to add a mute icon for people to be able to turn it off. I don't need any other functions, just the mute. I'm trying to avoid flash at all cost, but would be willing to use jQuery if possible. I don't think there are CSS methods.

I've googled and can't really find anything I need and I don't have experience with music and websites, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<embed name="lostmojo" src="music/atlast.mp3" loop="false" hidden="true" autostart="true">
```

Comment: http://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/javascriptjquery-to-control-html5-audio-elements/

Comment: possible duplicate of [mute and unmute button toggle html5 audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798530/mute-and-unmute-button-toggle-html5-audio)

Answer (score 1):

First you are favoured by using the audio tag instead of embed. You can use the pause method on the audio tag.

```
<audio id="lostmojo" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="annoyingsound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<img src="mute.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('lostmojo').pause()" />
```

*This time it should work ;)*

Comment: Totally understand all of this, but it's not working for some reason.

    <img src="images/mute.png" width="34" height="31" alt="mute" onclick="document.getEelementById("lostmojo").pause()"/></div>

Comment: Do I need to change the "embed name="lostmojo" to something different?

Comment: LOL! Love "annoying sound" Considering renaming the audio file to that. Anyway, this worked great thank you :D It won't let me upvote you though D:

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery:
Give the audio element an id (for example "lostmojo"):

```
<embed name="lostmojo" id="lostmojo" src="music/atlast.mp3" loop="false" hidden="true" autostart="true">
```

After that define an img tag to the mute button with an id:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="mute"/>
```

Then uses JQuery:

`$("#mute").click(function() {$("#lostmojo").pause();});`

Comment: Is there supposed to be an extra "=" sign in there? This line is confusing me:
 
id=src="lostmojo" music/atlast.mp3"

Comment: I assume it's this: <embed name="lostmojo" id="lostmojo" src="music/atlast.mp3" loop="false" hidden="true" autostart="true">

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="lostmojo" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="annoyingsound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<img src="mute.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('lostmojo').pause()" />
```

Change the mp3 to mpeg. Make sure you have those images and sounds. If That Doesent Work try Removing the .mp3 at the end of your src

```
<audio id="lostmojo" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="annoyingsound" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<img src="mute.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('lostmojo').pause()" />
```