# One click to mute another click to unmute

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mute

I have a simple website with menu that contains sound on hover, I added a button to mute the sound but the problem is when I click the button again to unmute sound it doesn't work.

```
<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('single-beep');
function enableMute() { 
audio.muted = true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and native JS? You can try audio.play(); which would be more consistent as a start.

Comment: If you read the enableMute function it's pretty clear why it isn't going to unmute the player. `(muted=true)` you need to check if the player is muted or not so you can toggle true/false

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I should use this very simple code:

```
 audio.muted = !audio.muted;
```

I found the answer here:

[mute and unmute button toggle html5 audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798530/mute-and-unmute-button-toggle-html5-audio)

Comment: Yes, that's working. I've tested your code in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/k8o4p2t4/),